# RNN input shapes for timeseries with sliding window

Tags: pytorch, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

Hi I am following examples from the book Time Series Forecasting using Deep Learning: Combining PYTORCH, RNN, ...
Unfortunately some of the function in the book are incomplete and hence I am struggling to figure out what the input shapes should be for the RNN Layer ...

```
# Sliding window function
def sliding_window(ts, features):

    x = []
    y = []

    for i in range(features + 1, len(ts) + 1):
        x.append(ts[i - (features + 1):i - 1])
        y.append([ts[i - 1]])

    return x,y

# Interpolates any missing values if any
def interpolated_timeseries(ts:pd.Series):
    return ts.interpolate()

# Returns timeseries sequence, sliding window size
def get_training_datasets(ts, features, test_size):

    ts = interpolated_timeseries(ts).tolist()
    X,y = sliding_window(ts, features)
    
    
    # Test split
    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = X[:-test_size],y[:-test_size],X[-test_size:],y[-test_size:]
    # Validation split
    val_size = int(0.35 * len(X_train))
   
    X_train,y_train,X_val,y_val = X_train[:-val_size],y_train[:-val_size],X_train[-val_size:],y_train[-val_size:]

    return X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test 

x_train,y_train,x_val,y_val,x_test,y_test = get_training_datasets(
    ts = pd.Series(scaled_ts.flatten()), 
    features = features, 
    test_size = 300
)

x_train = torch.FloatTensor(x_train)
...
```

The `get_training_datasets()` function is from a previous chapter as I couldn't find the function in the same chapter and some amendments had to be made work with the dataset.
It return which returns a training dataset of size `torch.Size([78477,240])` as well as testing and validation sets

```
# RNN Model
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, in_size, out_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size = in_size, hidden_size = hidden_size, batch_first = True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features = hidden_size, out_features = out_size)

    def forward(self, x, h_0 = None):
        rnn_out, h_n = self.rnn(x, h_0) 
        y_hat = self.fc(rnn_out.view(len(x), -1))
        return y_hat[-1], rnn_out[:,-1] # last hidden state

model = RNN(hidden_size = 24, in_size = 1, out_size = 1)
```

```
# Training
optimizer = optim.Adam(params = model.parameters(), lr = 0.02)
mse_loss = nn.MSELoss()
best_model = None
min_val_loss = sys.maxsize

training_loss = []
validation_loss = []

for t in range(training_epochs):
    prediction, _ = model(x_train.unsqueeze(0))
    ...
```

In the book they run training loop using, `model.forward(x_train)`, however I figured I need add an extra dimension to account for the batch size (which I am going to guess is accounted for in the `get_training_dataset()` function in the book)

Shape of training set I input, `torch.Size[1,78477,240]` (`x_train.unsqueeze(0).shape`) which follows the format for `batch=True` from pytorch documentation (batch_size, sequence_length, input_size)

I ofcourse get a dimension error
`RuntimeError: input.size(-1) must be equal to input_size. Expected 1, got 240`

So I am wondering what seems incorrect.
Also I am a bit confused on why the book inputs all the training data at once when considering a sliding window. I may be wrong but I was under the impression that you add the data relevent to each sliding window and get the prediction step by step using inner for loop.

Something of the sorts of

```
for t in range(training_epochs):
    for x_sliding in x_train:
       prediction, _ = model(x_sliding.unsqueeze(0))
```

Any explanation on this is much appreciated
Thanks